# Linear algebra doubt

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $S$ be a non empty subset of it. Can $\operatorname{span}(S)$ contain more number of vectors than in $V$, when

1. $S=V$?
2. $\operatorname{span}(S)=V$?

Comment: Indeed the span of $S$ can be characterized as the intersection of all *subspaces* of $V$ that contain $S$.  Thus in particular the span of $S$ is a subset (as well as a subspace) of $V$.

Answer (score 3):

No, because your vector space V has to be closed under forming of linear combinations to be a vector space. So every linear combination of elements of V, especially those in S, have to lie already in V. Since the Span of S only exists of linear combinatios i can't 'leave' V with the elements of S. If i consider everything over the same field, that is.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "more number of vectors," you mean "greater cardinality," or maybe "greater dimension."

1. $V$ is a vector space, so it is closed under addition and multiplication by scalars. This means that span$(V)\subset V$. Since $V \subset$ span$(V)$, we have span$(V)=V$ for any vector space $V$. In fact, this is how vector spaces are created. Any vector space $V$ can be written as the linear span of a particular set of vectors in $V$. Such a set is called a basis for $V$.
2. $S =$ span$(V)$, so we can't possibly have a vector in span$(V)$ that is not in $V$.